# how to stub a method for a specific argument in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to stub a method like so:

```
allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).with(:premium_plus_features_beta).and_return(false)
```

but when it hits a different argument - it gives me an error like this:

```
  #<Flipper (class)> received :enabled? with unexpected arguments
          expected: (:premium_plus_features_beta)
               got: (:non_advertiser_profile_amp, {:lawyer_id=>4469860})
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[:premium_plus_features_beta]
       +[:non_advertiser_profile_amp, {:lawyer_id=>4469860}]
```

I normally don't stub this much but why when I explicitly tell it the arguments, why is it erroring on different arguments? They are obviously not the same. Is this just some syntax issue?

#### edit 1

I tried this but doesn't work
https://makandracards.com/makandra/30543-rspec-only-stub-a-method-when-a-particular-argument-is-passed

```
Flipper.should_receive(:enabled?).and_call_original
Flipper.should_receive(:enabled?).with(:premium_plus_features_beta).and_return(false)
```

Comment: Look at this https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-4/docs/method-stubs. You could add as many params as you want: `.with(:premium_plus_features_beta, :non_advertiser_profile_amp)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When stubbing methods with specific arguments, you are only stubbing that specific method call with those specific parameters. All other calls to the method will fail with the error:

```
 #<Foo (class)> received :bar with unexpected arguments
```

As the OP discovered, the solution here is to first stub ALL calls to the object with the `and_call_through` method, then stub the specific calls with the specific  arguments you wish to stub.

From the OP's answer, the first line stubs ALL calls to the Flipper object and allows them to call through to the underlying code, and the second line stubs the call that receives `:premium_plus_features_beta` and returns `false`:

```
allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).and_call_original
allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).with(:beta).and_return(false)
```

Also, there's one other point to be made here. The code in the OP question used the OLD RSpec expectation syntax. The code in the OP answer uses the NEW RSpec stub syntax. So, when the code said this:

```
Flipper.should_receive(:enabled?).and_call_original
Flipper.should_receive(:enabled?).with(:beta).and_return(false)
```

What it was doing was this:

```
expect(Flipper).to have_received(:enabled?).and_call_original
expect(Flipper).to have_received(:enabled?).with(:beta).and_return(false)
```

Which is entirely different than what I think the OP was really trying to do:

```
before do
  allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).and_call_original
  allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).with(:beta).and_return(enabled?)
end

context "when the beta is disabled" do 
  let(:enabled?) { false }

  it "hides the beta" do
    ...
  end
end

context "when the beta is enabled" do 
  let(:enabled?) { true }

  it "shows the beta" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Finally, for those who are curious about why RSpec changed the syntax... The old syntax required a monkey patch on `Object` in order to add the `should_receive` method. I think the RSpec team preferred the new syntax because it no longer required the monkey patch.

Answer (score 1):

The working answer is:

```
allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).and_call_original
allow(Flipper).to receive(:enabled?).with(:premium_plus_features_beta).and_return(false)
```

a bunch of bad info on the internet lol